# Incompatible shapes in Keras but model.summary() seems ok

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm-stateful

Below is my Model

```
# Since we are predicting a value for every timestep, we set return_sequences=True
input = Input(batch_shape=ip_shape)
mLSTM = LSTM(units=32, return_sequences=True, stateful=True)(input)
mDense = Dense(units=32, activation='linear')(input)
mSkip = Add()([mLSTM, mDense])

mSkip = Dense(units=1, activation='linear')(mSkip)
model = Model(input, mSkip)

adam = Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss=total_loss)
model.summary()
```

Model Summary

```
Model: "model_3"
_______________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape                 Param #   Connected to                  
===============================================================================================
 input_5 (InputLayer)        [(104, 22050, 1)]            0         []                            
                                                                                                  
 lstm_4 (LSTM)               (104, 22050, 32)             4352      ['input_5[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 dense_5 (Dense)             (104, 22050, 32)             64        ['input_5[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 add_3 (Add)                 (104, 22050, 32)             0         ['lstm_4[0][0]',              
                                                                     'dense_5[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 dense_6 (Dense)             (104, 22050, 1)              33        ['add_3[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
===============================================================================================
Total params: 4449 (17.38 KB)
Trainable params: 4449 (17.38 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_______________________________________________________________________________________________
```

I am using a custom loss function. I am not sure if it could be messing with the shapes while backproping

```
def total_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    ratio = 0.5
    dc_loss = math_ops.pow(math_ops.subtract(math_ops.mean(y_true, 0), math_ops.mean(y_pred, 0)), 2)
    dc_loss = math_ops.mean(dc_loss, axis=-1)
    dc_energy = math_ops.mean(math_ops.pow(y_true, 2), axis=-1) + 0.00001
    dc_loss = math_ops.div(dc_loss, dc_energy)

    esr_loss = math_ops.squared_difference(y_pred, y_true) 
    esr_loss = math_ops.mean(esr_loss, axis=-1)
    esr_energy = math_ops.mean(math_ops.pow(y_true, 2), axis=-1) + 0.00001
    esr_loss = math_ops.div(esr_loss, esr_energy)

    return (ratio)*dc_loss + (1-ratio)*esr_loss
```

Finally the error: Let me know if the whole traceback is needed

```
InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

...

Incompatible shapes: [104,22050,32] vs. [32,22050,1]
     [[{{node gradient_tape/total_loss/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_9604]
```

Setting stateful=False seems to work but I don't get why

Answer (score 0):

You might consider:

```
model.add(Flatten())
```

It would help if you flattened the prediction somewhere.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP. Providing a full code snippet might help people new to the language understand the problem and where they went wrong.